# can not use trunc from dual ina JPA query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I'm using data JPA in my springboot project, and I need to use the trunc function in my sql @query, but the code does not compile.
The goal is to select the last day of the year from a date given in parameter :

```
@Query("DELETE FROM myTable" +
    "WHERE DAB_ID = :dabId " +
    "AND BIRTH_DATE BETWEEN :startDate " +
    "AND select trunc(to_date(:startDate, 'dd/mm/yy'), 'y') + interval '1' year - 1 from DUAL " +
    "AND (to_char(id.activityDate, 'D') IN (1,2,3,4,5)) ")
Publisher<Long> deleteByYearBirth(Long dabId , Date startDate);
```

```
technos: oracle, Java 11, hibernate, JPA

thanks for your help in advance,

i tried many solutions but I didn't succeed.
```

Comment: The above code won't even _compile_.  You should at least post valid Java code.

Comment: You haven't said what problem/error you have. But your parentheses look wrong; and you're treating `:startdate` as a date and then as a string - if it is a date then don't use `to_date()` on it...

Answer (score 0):

This is a native query so you must set "nativeQuery = true":

```
@Query("DELETE FROM myTable" +
    "WHERE DAB_ID = :dabId " +
    "AND BIRTH_DATE BETWEEN :startDate " +
    "AND select trunc(to_date(:startDate, 'dd/mm/yy'), 'y') + interval '1' year - 1 from DUAL " +
    "AND (to_char(id.activityDate, 'D') IN (1,2,3,4,5)) ",
    nativeQuery = true)
Publisher<Long> deleteByYearBirth(Long dabId , Date startDate);
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback, the code compiles now but still have the QuerySyntaxException error. the query works fine in Oracle Sql developer.

Comment: Can you please post the error?

Comment: "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: interval near line 1, column 230 [DELETE FROM ....]", stacktrace: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: interval near line 1, column 230  org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)

Comment: And you added the nativeQuery attribute?

Comment: Also try to add @Modifying